# Complicated query with active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord, will-paginate

I have been trying to figure out this query the whole day, and I have no idea how to get it.

I have a model `Book`

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Relationships
    has_many :requests, dependent: :destroy
end
```

and this model `Request`

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :book

    # Enumerables
    enum status: [:pending, :accepted, :completed]
end
```

I want to make a query to get Books that:

1. Do not have any request
2. Do have requests, but none of them is with status `:completed`

**My 2 cents:**

I managed to make them separate:

```
scope :without_requests, -> {
    requested_books_ids = Request.pluck(:book_id)
    where.not(id: requested_books_ids)
}

scope :with_requests_but_not_completed, -> {
    includes(:requests).where.not(requests: {status: Request.statuses[:completed] })
}
```

But I did not have any success joininig the results together. I tried this:

```
@books = Book.without_requests + Book.with_requests_but_not_completed
@books = @books.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 2)
```

But this failed with [the will_paginate gem](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate)

Any suggestion?

**UPDATE**

Not sure if relevant... but I am using SQLite for development and testing, and Postgresql for production. I heard that it was better to have the same system on all, but that shouldn't change the result for the queries, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is not bad. If you want to stick with it, what about the following:

```
Book.all
    .eager_load(:requests)
    .where([
      "books.id not in (?) or requests.status <> ?",
      Request.pluck(:book_id),
      Request.statuses[:completed]
    ])
```

`eager_load` is basically `includes(:requests)` + `references(:status)` which you should use. In this case you want the join so I preferred to use eager load, you can check this article which greatly explains [what eager_load is](http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/)

Comment: THAT WORKED! :) Just one small correction, you need parenthesis around the first `?` in your query. I`ll correct it and approve it.

Comment: Also that link gave me headache :D

Comment: Oh you are right, forgot brackets around `?`. Well that link helped me understanding it, you can ignore the first part and go straight to the last if you want. Good luck anyway! ;)

Comment: Another issue I found with this solution. If the `Request`table is empty, the first condition becomes `books.id not in (NULL)`, which some DB configurations can cause trouble. I did a `COUNT` check before hand, and substitute it with an empty string if that was the case.

Answer (score 0):

This could be easily done with raw SQL, but it seems that you want to rely on the DSL provided by ActiveRecord.

You need `OR`, which is unfortunately not available.
Your best bet is to implement it yourself, for example with this method:

```
def join_with_or(*relations)
  relations.map do |relation|
    clause = relation.arel.where_sql.sub(%r{\AWHERE }, '')
    "(#{clause})"
  end.join(' OR ')
end


one = Book.where.not(id: Request.pluck(:book_id))
two = Book.joins(:requests).where.not(requests: { status: Request.statuses[:completed] })

Book.where(join_with_or(one, two))
```

Comment: Yes, [arel](https://rubygems.org/gems/arel) is the "query builder" that ActiveRecord uses under the hood.

Comment: You can use it directly if you need low-level access to the underlying structure of your DB tables.

Comment: for the SQL... try to run the code in my answer, it should print the resulting SQL in the console log.

Comment: oh, you're working with SQLlite? Not sure why, but you're missing a JOIN. Try to open the console and step in the method chain. what's the result of `where_sql`?

Comment: Also, try with: `Book.joins(:requests).where(join_with_or(one, two))`

Comment: Sqlite only on development. Production uses Postgresql. Also I didnt understand your request, sorry. What do I need to do in the console?

Comment: With  `.joins` it gave me 0 records. This was the content of the log: http://pastebin.com/1sDTG2u2

Comment: you should invoke the methods one by one, adding more calls to the chain and check the results. Also, you should really use the same DB in production and dev, because there will be diffrerences. If you're on OS X try [this](http://postgresapp.com/), on Linux you can install it with a package manager.